# NSTextField transparent background

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I create *transparent* `NSTextField`

```
self.myTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(backgroundView.frame.origin.x + backgroundView.frame.size.width + 20, self.projectTitle.frame.origin.y - 30.0, 100, 20)];
self.myTextField.editable = NO;
self.myTextField.bezeled = NO;
self.myTextField.drawsBackground = YES;
self.myTextField.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
self.myTextField.selectable = NO;
self.myTextField.font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:16];

    [self addSubview:self.compressingTime];
```

And as a result text look bad. [image]
If I set background color

```
    self.myTextField.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1.0];
```

everything looks ok[image]
I have also tried with `drawsBackground = NO;` Do you guys know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "look bad"? It looks good to me?

Comment: @Vervious On the second img it looks like antialiasing is on, font on the firts img is rugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `CATextLayer` instead `NSTextField`.

Answer (score 82):

The secret is setting ALL THREE of these properties on the `NSTextField`...

```
myTextField.bezeled         = NO;
myTextField.editable        = NO;
myTextField.drawsBackground = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly for modifying the Apple code for programmatically populating an NSTableView

Comment: this only works if the superview's layer has a solid background color. @ZsoltSzatmari

Comment: This is the best answer. When creating the NSTextView in code you have to set .isBezeled to false or your view won't be transparent due to the bezel layer. Thanks Alex!

Comment: ah the joys of AppKit, always the most intuitive solutions

Comment: In my Xcode9 and OSX 10.13.2, `myTextField.bezeled` should be `myTextField.isBezeled`. And `myTextField.editable` should be `myTextField.isEditable`.

Answer (score 19):

There is a property in the .xib file, on the interface builder window for the text field, under attribute inspector

1. Check the Display Draws Background
2. Select a background color. Select clear color for transparent background.

[image]

Comment: Fixed my problem by Draws Background checked and set background color to clear color

Comment: This, not the higher ranked solution, worked for me.

Comment: Also, the border (bezel) needs to be set to "none" (the dotted box shown in the illustration) in my case.  Was fussing with this for several minutes until I pulled up the illustration and saw the additional difference

Answer (score 7):

As of 10.12 you can just do:

```
let label = NSTextField(labelWithString: "HELLO")
```

Answer (score 2):

Came here looking for this too, and have got the background to give me a transparent grey.   Key is to not have a bezel.   My code below:

```
NSTextField *yourLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width , height * 1.0/3.0)];
yourLabel.editable = false;
yourLabel.bezeled = false;
[yourLabel setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:0.1]];
```

For completeness I had got the width and height earlier because they get used many times for layout:

```
height = self.window.frame.size.height;
width = self.window.frame.size.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. Default appearance is empty. I try set dark mode and it work.

```
self.nameTextField.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark];
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem just now. I fixed it by **removing a property named `backgroundColor`** from the NSTextField's superview.

I was using `backgroundColor` just as a convenience getter/setter for the CALayer properties on an NSView subclass. Although this property isn't documented on NSView, it looks like I had accidentally overridden a property on NSView.

Yay for subclassing!

Answer (score -4):

The clear color will make the current view (ie)NSTextView's background as transparent hence the color of NSView which holds the NSTextView is visible.