# NSTextField draws partially transparent text when drawsBackground = YES

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have an `NSTextField`. I want it to draw text and have a background color. But when I set `drawsBackground` to `YES`, the text seems to draw partially transparently. For example, if I set the text color to white and background to black, the text comes out gray. Why is this?

Comment: This may be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120654/nstextfield-transparent-background

Comment: In my project I set text color [textView setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]]; and set bg color  [textView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]]; Text is not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `isEnabled` set to `true`.

I was seeing this as well and changing this fixed it for me.