# Transparent background of NSTextfield NSPopover

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nspopover

Disclaimer: This question is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120654/nstextfield-transparent-background) question

I am trying to populate a Table in NSPopover.(As seen in the image)

---

**Problem:**
I am not able to make transparent background to NSTextField.

Strangely, it works fine if view is attached to NSWindow

---

(The names in window at left are having transparent background, but same view when seen in NSPopover fails to show transparent background to NSTextfield.)
[image]

Is this a bug in NSPopover or am I doing something wrong ?

---

This is my code to create Table cells

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    var cell = NSTableCellView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 40))
    var textField = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 20))

    // **For transparency**
    textField.stringValue = nameList[row]
    textField.bezeled = false
    textField.editable = false
    textField.drawsBackground = false

    cell.addSubview(textField)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an issue with the text field being rendered vibrantly, causing the white background of the table view around it to also be rendered vibrantly. This vibrancy causes a plusL blend mode, therefore becoming invisible).

This only happens in a popover because that's a vibrant context, and is setup with an `NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight` appearance by default.

Sessions 209 and 220 from WWDC2014 discuss a bit more about vibrancy, and the 10.10 release notes on NSVisualEffectView / vibrancy.

---

To workaround this, you can set the appearance of the table view to the `NSAppearanceNameAqua` appearance.

Comment: Sadly it's one of the least obvious things a person mildly new to the platform might suffer.